# Need to delete the last constraint with the direct target from all selected bones

Tags: python, bones, constraints

I copied one Copy Transform constrain to all my bones accidentally and didn't notice it at the right time. So I need to get rid of it now and it seems I can not just click and delete it for all selected bones.
So it seems to me that the scripting should be involved? My constraints didn't have unique names. So on some bones, this one goes like the one and only, on others it is named with .001 or .002. It shares two features though: it goes last in the list and also it has the same Target. So the question is how can I delete this specific constraint without touching others, using scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can't be done without scripting. But the script to delete last constraint is easy:

```
import bpy

for pose_bone in bpy.context.selected_pose_bones:
    if len(pose_bone.constraints):
        pose_bone.constraints.remove(pose_bone.constraints[-1])
```

Comment: How to Apply the constraint? Not delete.